# Random variable with infinite $(k+1)$th moment

Tags: probability-distributions

I was asked to give an example of a random variable which has finite $i$'th moments for $i=1,2,\ldots,k$ and has an unbounded $(k+1)$th moment.

Obviously, a Student-distributed $t_{k+1}$ random variable will work, but I suppose giving a proof link to Wikipedia is not an option, and dealing with density which involves Gamma function is far beyond my current level of maths.

1. Is there a simpler way to show the desired property for Student distribution? If not,
2. Are there any simpler examples of random variables with this desired property?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hint:  The harmonic series diverges but what about the series whose $n$-th term is $n^{-i}$ for $i > 1$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is actually not that hard to show that a random variable that follows Student distribution with $k+1$ degrees of freedom satisfies this property. Since the probability density function is proportional to $\left( \frac{k+1}{k+1+x^2} \right)^{1+k/2}$ and since, for $k \geqslant 1$,
$$
 \left| x^r \left( \frac{k+1}{k+1+x^2} \right)^{1+k/2} \right| \geqslant \frac{ \vert x \vert^r }{\left( 1+ x^2 \right)^{1+k/2}}
$$
The integral defining $r$-th moment is only convergent for $1 \leqslant r \leqslant k$:
$$
    \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left\vert x^r \mathcal{N}_k \left( \frac{k+1}{k+1+x^2} \right)^{1+k/2} \right\vert \, \mathrm{d} x \geqslant \mathcal{N}_k \int_{-\infty}^\infty 
   \frac{ \vert x \vert^r }{\left( 1+ x^2 \right)^{1+k/2}} \mathrm{d} x = 2 \mathcal{N}_k \int_{0}^\infty \frac{ x^r }{\left( 1+ x^2 \right)^{1+k/2}} \mathrm{d} x
$$
The latter integral only converges at $+\infty$ if $r \leqslant k$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the discrete random variable with the probability as follows $$P_{\epsilon}(X = n) = \frac{\frac1{n^{k+1+\epsilon}}}{\zeta(k+1+\epsilon)}$$ for any $\epsilon \in (0,1]$.

$$\mathbb{E}(X^m) = \left \{ \begin{array}{cl} \frac{\zeta(k+1+\epsilon - m)}{\zeta(k+1+\epsilon)}  < \infty, &~~ \forall m \in \{1,2,\ldots,k\}\\
\infty, &~~ \forall m>k \end{array}\right.$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  Let $X$ have density function $f(x)=\dfrac{c}{x^{k+2}}$ for $x\ge 1$, and $f(x)=0$ elsewhere, where $c$ is chosen to make the integral equal to $1$.

You can also produce a discrete analogue of the above construction. For $n=1, 2, 3, \dots$, let $P(X=n)=\dfrac{c}{n^{k+2}}$ for a suitable constant $c$.

Comment: I was going to suggest the [Pareto distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution).  Mentioning that that's what it's called doesn't hurt.

Answer (score 2):

Take $X_n$ defined over $[1,\infty)$ such that 
$$
\mathbb P(X \le x) = \frac{\int_1^x \frac 1{x^{n+2}} \, dx}{C}, 
$$
where $C$ is
$$
C = \int_1^{\infty} \frac 1{x^{n+2}} \, dx.
$$
Therefore, 
$$
\mathbb E[X_n^k] = \frac 1C \int_1^{\infty} \frac 1{x^{n+2-k}} \, dx < \infty \qquad \text{ if } k = 1, \dots, n
$$
but diverges when $k = n+1$.

Hope that helps,

Comment: This doesn't work.  If the lower bound of integration is $0$, then $C=\infty$.  If you use a positive number such as $1$ as the lower bound, then it works.  That's the [Pareto distibution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution).

Comment: Dahhh, I wasn't careful. This is the second time I say dumb stuff this morning. Thanks.